# value na is not a member of?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

hello i just started to learn scala.
and just follow the tutorial in udemy.
i was followed the same code but give me an error.
i have no idea about that error.

and this my code

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, CountVectorizerModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row


Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val data = spark.read.option("header","true").
            option("inferSchema","true").
            option("delimiter","\t").
            format("csv").
            load("dataset.tsv").
            withColumn("subject", split($"subject", " "))

val logRegDataAll = (data.select(data("label")).as("label"),$"subject")
val logRegData = logRegDataAll.na.drop()
```

and give me error like this

```
scala> :load LogisticRegression.scala
Loading LogisticRegression.scala...
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, CountVectorizerModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@1efcba00
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: string, subject: array<string>]
logRegDataAll: (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName) = ([label: string],subject)
<console>:43: error: value na is not a member of (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName)
       val logRegData = logRegDataAll.na.drop()
                                      ^
```

thanks for helping

Comment: Isn't there an extra parantheses after `data("label")` in `logRegDataAll` whcih is converting in a tuple? Use `data.select(data("label").as("label"),$"subject")`

Answer (score 0):

You can see clearly

```
val logRegDataAll = (data.select(data("label")).as("label"),$"subject")
```

This returns

```
(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName)
```

So there is an extra parantheses `)`  data("label"))   which should be `data.select(data("label").as("label"),$"subject")` in actual.